# Maximizing a sum over points with distance constraint in 3D

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization

### Problem

The problem statement is as follows, given a set of points in 3D, `p_i`, and their corresponding energy value, `e_i`, find a subset of them in which the sum of their energy is maximized, and the distance between each two selected points is greater than a constant `r`.

### What I did so far

These are a summary of my thoughts so far, which I guess are helpful, but may be misleading.

1. A Greedy algorithm: sorting points by their energy value, which isn't guaranteed to give the optimal answer.
2. Generalizing the problem: Graph Model, I created a graph in which each vertex represents a point and two points are connected if and only if they are close enough (their distance is less than r). The goal is now to select an independent set that maximizes the energy function.
   The problem is now NP-hard (Independent set problem reduces to this, set `e_i`s to 1), which means, if I don't use the spatial properties of the points and assume that space metric is a completely arbitrary function, then the problem is not solvable.
3. Knowing that, I tried to solve the 1D case, in which points lay on a line, AND I DID IT.
   After sorting points by their `x` value, let `dp[i][j]` represent the answer to the problem when we only use the first `i`th of the points while committing to an extra constraint: distance between each of `x_k`s (k < i) and `x_j` must be less than `r`. This means that we want to solve the problem for the first `i` elements while still having the possibility of selecting `x_j` afterward.
   A dynamic programming algorithm can be constructed from this formulation.

I found the difference between 3. and 2. is that, when we sort the points, if for example `p_1` and `p_2` don't have a conflict then `p_1` and `p_i`, `i > 2` don't conflict at all (by conflicting I mean being closer than `r`). precisely:
in the sorted array for each `i, j, k; i < j < k` we have `p_i < p_j < p_k`, therefore
`p_j - p_i > r` results `p_k - p_i > r`.
I think this is what makes the difference and reduces the complexity from NP-Hard to `O(n^2)`

I was trying to generalize my answer to the 2D case but I got stuck, firstly I tried to sort points by their distance from the original, which doesn't satisfy the property mentioned above, then I tried sorting by their radial angle, again found out I'm not smart enough.

I don't know much about computational geometry, but I feel the answer lies behind some of the techniques used there.

### Where did this come from

This is a subproblem of a vision task, to avoid any XY problem, I will explain the original question too, even though I might be complicating this particular subproblem, I found it interesting and will appreciate any help.

The original problem: Assume I have a video of an object sitting on a known marker pattern (ArUco Board) using which I can find camera transformation. I want to compute a point cloud from the surface of the object. I can use each frame and calculate matrix `F` and then match the image to other images, but firstly, the time complexity is annoying, secondly, most of the frames are very close to each other and we know that low parallax causes higher error. Finally, some images are blurry due to motion.

So I thought, I may compute the reprojection error of the markers as a factor indicating how good a frame is, and set a minimum distance between frames that are selected for matching and surface extraction.

Comment: casting your _actual_ problem to be a ***combinatorial problem*** just makes your life harder for no good reason. do not do this. your formulation looks like it's in NP, with approximations and heuristics conceivable but still I can't see why this problem formulation should in any way be useful to your actual problem. actually, I think this entire post is close to meaningless. there's not even a [mre] or data or a coherent presentation of the issue.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced with your explanation for why the problem is not NP-Hard. Since the points are in a 2d space, it's not clear what you mean by sorting the points - are you trying to sort them by x coordinate, then y coordinate or their energy? In either case, because the points are in 2d space we can probably come up with a counterexample for any metric used to show that, given `pi, pi+1, pi+2` are in the sorted order with `pi, pi+1`, `pi+1,pi+2` not conflicting, it is not necessarily true that `pi,pi+2` do not conflict.

Comment: @user3386109 The question enforces that selected points are far apart. In the graph I created I connected points that are close together so I can say that problem without metric is equivalent to Independence set.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz At first I wanted to create two separate posts for this and the original question. At this stage I just want to somehow solve it. I may remove the `where did this come from` section.

Comment: @wLui155 I never said it's not NP-Hard. I know that in graph-model it is NP-Hard and in 1D case it can be solved in `O(n^2)`. 
I am only guessing that 1D case can be extended to 2D and 3D. But I have almost no idea how.

Comment: maybe take this to the Stack Exchanges for math or theoretical computer science. it's certainly not a programming problem but a problem of modeling your actual task in ways that don't end up being NP or otherwise convoluted.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Okay I'll do that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Mixed-Integer Programming Model for this problem:

[image]

With 100 2d points, random locations, random energy levels, mindist=50, I get:

```
----     42 VARIABLE x.L  selected points

point7  1,    point15 1,    point22 1,    point50 1,    point89 1
```

[image]

This took 0 seconds to optimize (using a good MIP solver).

For 100 3d points, the solution was:

```
----     42 VARIABLE x.L  selected points

point1  1,    point5  1,    point20 1,    point34 1,    point41 1,    point58 1,    point63 1,    point67 1,    point79 1
point98 1
```

Also took 0 seconds. Increasing the 3d problem size to 1000 points: 4 seconds.

It is a misconception that a given NP Hard problem, with a given data set, must take lot of time to solve as a MIP.